# Критика кода одного приложения

Tags: java, android, инспекция-кода

Всем привет! Хотелось бы узнать ваше мнение насчет того как я пишу код приложений. Прошу строго судить, показать пальцем на все, за что могут бранить на работе, в команде, ну вообщем, по полной. Не знаю можно ли тут так делать, но все же рискну. Код на гитхабе > https://github.com/ATumbler/metropolis/tree/master/server/so. Выложил только то, что меня интересует

Спасибо!

Comment: Оооо... я также пишу. Комментариев только не хватает.

Comment: Конвенцию оформления java кода не соблюдаете совсем. Фигурную скобку без новой строки нужно писать, camelCase использовать, объявлять класс переменной только нужного интерфейса (List - ArraytList). Используйте IDE и автоформатирование.

Comment: @Victor Khovanskiy, эх, моя IDE это AIDE, я пишу код в смартфоне, автоформатирование там по умолчанию такое, знаю что скобки не айс.

Comment: А по поводу самого кода? :)

Comment: Зачем вы в файл readme.me пишете такое описание? Такое описание лучше добавлять к комментарию коммита, а результат проделанной работы лучше маркеровать не датами, а номером версии.

Comment: @Данил, я на гитхабе отроду неделя, раньше как свалка она у меня была, спасибо за замечание

Comment: Вот это `input.equals("")` целесообразно заменить на это `input.isEmpty()`, ибо второе работает быстрее. Безотносительно вопроса – советую почитать известную книжку Д. Блоха.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если идти сверху вниз по коду, то:

1) Массовые беспорядочные импорты (Вам оно всё действительно надо?).

2) Не пользуетесь модификаторами доступа.

3) Не соблюдаете правила именования переменных.

4) `Context` в `Activity` вынесен зачем-то в поле класса (в случае с Activity не лучше ли использовать `this`?).

5) Инициализация `List<UserModel> users` вынесена в отдельный метод, когда можно было сделать это сразу же в поле класса, где эта переменная объявлена.

6) Инициализацию  `UserAdapter adapter` после п.4 казалось бы можно было сделать в поле класса, где эта переменная объявлена, но если хорошо подумать, то вынесена она отдельно, только, чтобы однажды обновить этот адаптер. `RecyclerView` вам предоставит адаптер по требованию `.getAdapter()`.

7) Некоторые `View` вынесены в поля класса, но используются единожды за весь код, а некоторые используются вообще в момент их же инициализации. Например переменная `fab_add` инициализируется в `onCreate` в одном методе, а используется единожды всё в том же `onCreate`, но в другом методе. В данном случае, с опытом предыдущих пунктов, от вынесения кода в методы `initViews()`, `setupViews()`, `initAdapter()` следует отказаться, тогда и переменную `fab_add` в поле класса выносить не придётся.

8) Строковые ресурсы принято выносить в отдельный файл string, расположенный в ресурсах проекта.

9) Постоянное создание нового объекта `new Handler()`, когда каждая `View` содержит в себе `Handler`. Возьмите любую из ваших `View`, вынесенных в поле класса и скажите ей `.post` или `.postDelayed`.

10) Постоянное создание объектов на протяжении всего кода.. `new Response.Listener()`, `new Runnable()`, `new Response.ErrorListener()`.. , Вас когда-нибудь проклянёт сборщик мусора. Например разные вариации `new Runnable()`, которые,  если вглядываться, вероятно часто вызываются. Вот тут как раз стоило бы вынести данные объекты `Runnable` в поле класса проинициализировав однажды, после чего взывая к ним.

11) Такой перенос скобок мб и используется в таких языках, как `C++`, но в `Java` привычнее всё таки фигурную скобку открывать без новой строки. Если к этому поудалять лишние пробелы и учесть предыдущие пункты, то в классе `UserActivity` количество строк кода можно будет сократить с 400 до 200-250 (навскидку).

Это я просмотрел только один класс `UserActivity`. Остальные смотреть лень :)

Comment: Ого, огромное спасибо! Насчет пункта 9 - тоесть вы советуете вместо создания нового обьект переинициализировать старый?

Comment: Про 9 пункт - просто зачем создавать новый объект Handler, когда он уже существует в ближайшем стандартном компоненте :) А почему вы везде задержку в секунду делаете? Так дизайнерами задумано?

Comment: Нет, просто сетевые запросы быстрые и я не нашел другого способа удерживать статус выполнения. Окно дергано появлялось/исчезало

Answer (score 1):

Перед критикой: в общем неплохо, я бы даже сказал очень неплохо. Твердая 4.

**Теперь критика:**

1. Нарушение стиля именований - сильно смущает имя интерфейса `TrigListener` - неужели трудно было назвать `TriggerListener`?
2. Вообще что мешало `TriggerListener` сделать публичным внутренним классом `TriggerActivity`? Целостность кода не нарушалось бы
3. Сильно увлекаетесь анонимными классами - "ступеньки" кода как бы иллюстрируют проблему читаемости кода. Можно бы кое-где и разбавить лямбда выражениями
4. Есть некоторые стилистические проблемы с фигурными скобками - то они всегда с новой строки, то они на старой строке
5. Одинарные `if/else` зря обрамляете фигурными скобками
6. Хотя бы в бинах надо бы применять `private`
7. Почти не используете аннотации (кроме самоочевидной `@Override`) - рекомендую присмотреться к [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)
8. Конструкцию

`public class TriggerActivity
extends AppCompatActivity 
implements OnClickListener,
TrigListener`

я бы написал так:

`public class TriggerActivity
     extends AppCompatActivity 
       implements OnClickListener, TriggerListener`

Comment: Все проблемы из-за моей IDE нс смартфоне, аннотации юзать нельзя, автокоррекция кода самв выносит так скобки, насчет if-else - где-то читал, что наоборот плохо обрамлять одинарные строки, про модификаторы доступа честно забываю...  эх долго я буду привыкать к AS. Спасибо!

Comment: Можно покритиковать? :) По пятому пункту – в java code conventions сказано как раз `if statements always use braces {}`.